# 3D topographic progress compensation by the least squares method

Tags: 3d, topography

I'm looking for an explanation of the least squares method used in the case of a correction of 3D point network.

We have reference points with known coordinates XYZ. We calculate intermediate points based on chaining from the starting point (reference point) until we reach the end point (other reference point). We then calculate the difference between the measured coordinates and known coordinates of the end point, so the difference is the cumulative error. We now have to split the cumulative error between all measured points by a least square method.

So please does someone have a document explaining the mathematical formulas, what to do, and sample application of this method?

Comment: It's usually done using total length (L) and individual segment lengths (l), i.e. dx=DX/L×l, where DX is cum. X error. Same with dy.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Please edit some extra info into the body of the question for clarification: What do you mean by "topographic progress"? What do you mean by "chaining" -- is it measuring distance? Is this a *trilateration* network? Are elevations involved? Are there any measured angles? Do you know what least-squares is? Do you need it? Can a traditional (non-LS) method of adjustment suffice?